# Heat equation integral restricted to a sphere

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am new to SE, so hopefully, I am asking this in the right format. I have the following integral, which comes out of a heat equation problem:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-{|x-y|^2/(4Dt)}}g(|y|) dy$$

where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $g(|y|) = c$ for $|y|\leq \alpha$ and $g(y)=0$ for $|y|>\alpha$. It seems logical to compute this integral in spherical coordinates, given that $g(|y|)$ restricts the integral to a sphere of radius $\alpha$, but the integrand does not just depend on $|y|$ in the usual way. I can probably compute the integral in Cartesian coordinates, but it seems like there should be a better method. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try expressing $\exp(-|x-y|^2)$ as $\exp(-x^2)\exp(2x\cdot y)\exp(-y^2)$. The first term depends only on x, the last one is a constant on a sphere of fixed radius. Not sure what to do with the second term though.

Comment: One trick here is to pick the polar axis in spherical coordinates to lie along the $z$-axis. This amounts to choosing $\mathbf{x}=(0,0,h)$ for some $h$, and makes explicit the fact that you still have rotational symmetry around the $\mathbf{x}$-direction.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!